# HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Creating a Hibernate Test Project using maven.

when i run the project, it generates Exception:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:209)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at org.hibernate.hibernatetest.App.main(App.java:33)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.hibernatetest.App.main(App.java:51)
```

But in main class required properties are set.don't know why programme is genrAating exception.

Main Class:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration configuration;
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        configuration = new Configuration();


        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect ", "com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url ", "jdbc:sqlite:TailorDB.db");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class ", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username ", "");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password ", "");
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        CustomerModel c = new CustomerModel();
        c.setID(5);
        c.setNIC_Number("691201631345");
        c.setFirstName("Zee");
        c.setNumber("55225522");
        c.setLastName("Jan");
        c.setCustomerCode("Zee-123");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
}
```

In POM file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.applerao</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernatesqlite</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea where the problem can be??

CustomerModel cLass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")

public class CustomerModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "c_id")
int ID;
@Column(name = "c_code")
String customerCode;
@Column(name = "c_fname")
String firstName;
@Column(name = "c_mname")
String middleName;
@Column(name = "c_lname")
String lastName;
@Column(name = "c_nic")
String NIC_Number;
@Column(name = "c_email")
String email;
@Column(name = "c_pnumber")
String number;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You didn't initialize configuration, serviceRegistry, and sessionFactory correctly.
From Hibernate 4.3.2.Final, StandardServiceRegistryBuilder is introduced. Please follow this order to initialize, e.g.

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("com/jeecourse/config/hibernate.cfg.xml");

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

So in your code, you missed the step: `configuration.configure()`.

Comment: configure() is used when we want to add xml configuration file which is placed in project directory but i don't have to use that because i already defined all configuration properties in code.check after "serviceRegistry" declaration.

Comment: Thanks! I was following the [JBoss Hibernate tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers) where the snippet `new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build()` caused me this issue. After using `applySettings(configuration.getProperties())`, it worked.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be old question, but now when I am using 4.3.1 final Hibernate version I also came across this problem. After reading through many answers it seemed like they have really not taken care of it in the documentation but I went through the documentation and i think they have necessary information. It is not necessary that hibernate configuration needs to be in a .properties file, but it can be in xml file also.

Just make sure you invoke `configure()` before invoking `build()` on the instance of `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`. This is because configure() actually loads the configuration from the default cfg.xml file and build actually uses it.

To understand this, you can do one thing....before invoking `configure()` .... invoke `getSettings()` on the intance of `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` and print it...it's a Map.

You will not see any hibernate properties you have mentioned in the cfg.xml

Now invoke `configure()` and print `getSettings()` map....you will see...you have got all your properties.

Answer (score 5):

In hibernate 4.3, it seems that need to use hibernate.properties to do config,
use hibernate.cfg.xml only to include the .hbm.xml files,
so, following is the solution:

in classpath, add a file: hibernate.properties
and do all config here,
e.g:

```
# jdbc connecition
hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xdm
hibernate.connection.username = postgres
hibernate.connection.password = 123456

# dialect
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect

# c3p0
hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 2
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 5
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = 20
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 10
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 300
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = 3000
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout = true

# other
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.max_fetch_depth = 3
```

then, in hibernate.cfg.xml, only include the .hbm.xml files,
e.g:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="hibernate/model/Event.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

tip: the official document didn't give any tip like this, I think it's a very bad thing.

Comment: <quote>In hibernate 4.3, it seems that need to use hibernate.properties to do confi</quote> Is there any reference? thanks

Comment: @okwap I didn't find, but after try, it works this way when use hibernate standalone. When use with spring it works both way.

Comment: In that .hbm.xml is missing <property name="current_session_context_class">....</property> . Without that launched No CurrentSessionContext configured.

Comment: What if you had 2 different database vendors such as DB2 and Oracle, how would you set hibernate dialect in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Set the configuration properties before applying configuration properties to the settings of `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`

```
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlite:TailorDB.db");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Also, there seems to be a space at the end of the property keys while setting them. Please remove them.

Based on the [link](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/), try changing this

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect");
```

to

```
configuration.setProperty("dialect", "com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect");
```

Comment: Remove the spaces in the end of the property

Comment: didn't get it which spaces?

Comment: There is a space `configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect(space)", "com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect");` while setting the properties in the key value. remove it

Comment: removed and same result.

Comment: which datasource are you trying to connect? What is the dialect you specify? a custom one

Comment: is it necessary? i don't think i'm using

Comment: Did you try to change the property key based on the updated answer

Comment: yes tried by changing the property key based on answer..but not solved.same result

Comment: ServiceRegistryBuilder applySettings after cfg helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to make all the configurations in the code without `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `hibernate.properties`. Tested with hibernate version 4.3.8.Final. Hope it would be helpful.

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put(Environment.DRIVER,
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName());
    properties.put(Environment.USER, "root");
    properties.put(Environment.PASS, "root");
    properties.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
    properties.put(Environment.DIALECT, MySQL5Dialect.class.getName());
    properties
            .put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate_test");
    properties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);

    configuration.setProperties(properties);

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Stock.class).addAnnotatedClass(
            StockDailyRecord.class);

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
            .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. Somehow the 4.3.5 does not take the connection (Dialect) information from the hibernate.cfg.xml, use hibernate.properties file for that.

Answer (score 0):

As he say about ServiceRegistry :

```
package org.phenix.hibernate.main;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration object was reading all the properties from the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. But the `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` object was not using those properties.

This solution worked for me.  The below statement is critical in making this work:

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = 
    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
        configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

Full solution:

```
package demo.jaxrs.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            System.out.println("Properties: " + configuration.getProperties());
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

         }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the dialect cannot connect for any other reason, such as password expired.

Check for any earlier exceptions that may reveal the cause.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to connect to DB which is Mysql8+ version from my Java application. I face the same issue. The error logs are same but the reason for failure is different.

I made the change in my.cnf file of Mysql and it is: `max-connect-errors=1000`

Default value is 100 but it wont work. So increases it to 1000, it starts working.

Need to look the logs in details in case of failure. If the logs contains this anywhere then try this thing.

> java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'X' is
>   blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin
>   flush-hosts'"

Answer (score 0):

@id annotation in entity class,

In My case forgot to add @id Annotation after all correct configuration, once i add the annotation its working fine

```
@Entity 
public class demo{

@Id
private long id

}
```