# Spring Boot - Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot application that should connect to a database using hibernate, however I am getting the following exception: `Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

My application.properties

```
server.port=9000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Users
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>1.1.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <start.class>com.server.boot.Starter</start.class>
    <spring.core.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.8</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.server"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Starter.class,args);
        System.out.println("started application");
    }   
    @Bean
    public LoginController loginController(){
        return new LoginController();
    }   
}
```

And my controller:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginController {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="username",required=true) String username, 
                        @RequestParam(value="password",required=true) String password){
        return "Tried to login as "+username + " where em is "+entityManager;
    }
}
```

What is the cause of this?

---

Upon further research

I believe the answer to this question [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null) solved it

Comment: For MySQL just add in the application.proeprties:
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: @pixel The OP themself confirmed that that question solved their problem. Please don't waste time of reviewers by pushing things unnecessarily into the reopen review queue.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I dont, provide option to remove request to reopen and problem solved as I explained it was by mistake.  But it looks like you are not aware of that, so obviously missing functionality to revert accidentaly requested reopen.  Maybe add that to save some time, just a suggestion

Comment: @pixel You seem to think I work for Stack Overflow, I do not. If you want to suggest improvements, you can do so on [meta].