# How configure spring multiple profiles databases javaconfig

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

### How to start a project with spring MVC with profiles, multiple connections to the database .. and run tests with gradle?

Some time ago I'm trying to make these settings and I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong?
(Sorry for my english I'm using google translate.)

Here are my settings
**Dev Settings**

```
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nextinfoerp
db.username=myuser
db.password=mypass

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql =true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=br.com.nextinfo.erp
```

**Test Settings**

```
#Test properties:
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nextinfoerptestdb
db.username=myuser
db.password=mypass

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql =true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=br.com.nextinfo.erp
```

**Gradle Settings**

```
 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'war'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
 apply plugin: 'jetty'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


ext.springVersion= '4.1.7.RELEASE'
ext.jacksondataTypeHibernate4 ='2.5.3'
ext.easycriteriaVersion ='3.0.0'
ext.hibernateCoreVersion ='4.3.10.Final'
ext.hibernateValidadeVersion ='5.1.3.Final'
ext.springDataVersion ='1.8.0.RELEASE'
ext.mysqlConnectionVersion= '5.1.6'
ext.servletApiVersion ='2.5'


dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile project(':utils')
 compile"javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"

 compile "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.2.RELEASE"
 compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:    servletApiVersion
  compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect', version: '1.2.9'



 compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
 compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
 compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
 compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE'



 compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: springVersion
 compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: springVersion
 compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: springVersion
 compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springVersion
 compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version:springDataVersion
 compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate4', version: jacksondataTypeHibernate4
 compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc4"
 compile group: 'uaihebert.com', name: 'EasyCriteria', version: easycriteriaVersion
 compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: hibernateValidadeVersion
 compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: hibernateCoreVersion
 compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateCoreVersion
 }
```

**class for database configuration**

```
package br.com.nextinfo.erp.web.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("dev")
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.nextinfo.erp.web.dao")
@PropertySource("classpath:dev.properties")
public class DevProfileDatabase extends AbstractDatabaseConfig implements PerfilDataBase {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DevProfileDatabase.class);

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    log.warn("settings  data Source "+this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
    return dataSource;
}    
@Bean   
protected Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
    return properties;
}
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    txManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getMetamodel().getEntities();
    return txManager;
}
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    log.warn("settings data entity manager "+this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}
```

}

**My class incializer**

```
 import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Order(1)
public class Inicializer extends         AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements  WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
     return new Class[] {ThymeleafConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {ThymeleafConfig.class,ProdProfileDatabase.class,DevProfileDatabase.class,TestProfileDatabase.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { };
}
@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    
    WebApplicationContext context = 
                 (WebApplicationContext)super.createRootApplicationContext();
        ((ConfigurableEnvironment)context.getEnvironment()).setActiveProfiles("dev");

        return context;
    
}
```

I'm using spring-data

the error
Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [br/com/nextinfo/erp/web/config/ProdProfileDatabase.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [br/com/nextinfo/erp/web/config/ProdProfileDatabase.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I remove the annotation profiles and classes that use the annotation inicializer function normally,
How do I solve this?

Comment: It looks like you are having this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null

Comment: the problem and I can not find an example with profiles, like that works more using profiles with gradle does not work, do not know what I did or am doing wrong! is roughly one week I'm trying to accomplish this task without more success! ..
I can not find a complete project with gradle using profiles and performing integration testing ..
Details the gradle i am using multi project

Comment: I solved problem movend Databases config for getRootConfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the database configuration classes to load along with the root settings

```
 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
 return new Class[] {ThymeleafConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
return new Class[]     {ThymeleafConfig.class,ProdProfileDatabase.class,DevProfileDatabase.class,TestPr   ofileDatabase.class};
}
```

### I did this exchange

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
  return new Class[] {ProdProfileDatabase.class,DevProfileDatabase.class,TestPr ofileDatabase.class};
  }

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
return new Class[]    {ThymeleafConfig.class};
}
```