# Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set.

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting exception even after setting hibernate.dialect property.
I am using hibernate 5.0.11 with spring boot 1.4.2 and mysql version as 5.7

```
application.properties is like this

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

What is issue here ?

Comment: Either set `spring.jpa.database-platform` or `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` instead of just `hibernate.dialect`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Adding the following line to the `properties` file solve this problem when I had that error.

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

Comment: Super saver... I found a lot of answers but I managed to come across this answer, I was lucky...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue post upgrading spring-boot-starter-parent version from 2.1.3.RELEASE to 2.2.5.RELEASE, tried all above options but no luck.
I am using spring boot and Hikari to connect to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Great, it works for me, as we use oracle database, so "spring.jpa.database=oracle" works fine for me.

Comment: For SQL Server: spring.jpa.database=SQL_SERVER. It works for me!

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Probably you already solved this, but I had a similar issue.

Adding explicit runtime dependency to mysql should solve the problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That allows spring boot to auto-configure jdbc related beans based on classpath.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not prevent the dialect resolution error.

Answer (score 2):

I also just had a similar issue, but realized I hadn't customized the DB name field properly from copy and pasting into the application.properties file created from Springboot's [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

Be sure to replace `db_example` `springuser` and `ThePassword` with your actual values.

Just a "duh" moment for myself, but may be of some use to others.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following after creating the Configuration solve the problem :

```
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was blatantly missing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also this post has some helpful tips: [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I started my spring boot application with the database excluded:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Then once I started creating JPA classes I got an error which I tried to fix with:

```
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
}
```

This led to the exception mentioned in the question.

So the solution was simply to remove `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` from the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation of course, but it took some time before I noticed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my Spring boot project upon connecting to an Oracle database.

These are the following steps I performed to troubleshoot-

1. Make sure relevant hibernate properties are present in **application.properties** file `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`,

   `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

   the dialect depends on which datbase you are using. Also the `hibernate.ddl-auto` can be one of the 5 properties.
2. Verify the JDBC url. For e.g. connection string for oracle is like `jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.32.20:1521/SRV_LICENSING_D1`
3. Verify the database credentials.
4. Make sure the service name used is in **upper case** in your property file. Because hibernate is **case sensitive**. For e.g. service name in case of oracle would be something like `SRV_LICENSING_D1`

Comment: none of these work

Comment: can you please post the files you are using: application.propoerties and JDBC url along with service name

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**: Database connection is not satisfied while dialects for db, which database is not important.

**Solution**: Correct connection string in application.properties (or where is it)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the access modifier to my custom DialectResolver. It was not `public`.. Rookie mistake :)