# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I know this is a commonly asked question, but none of the solutions available are working out for me. 
Below is my booltstraps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


<!--
    This configuration file configures the Database Access Object or DAO objects. 
    It is used at system start to bootstrap configurations. 
    DAO objects will also be used by the main PassMark application.
-->
    <bean class="com.passmarksecurity.utils.AppContext" id="appContext">
        <description>Simple bean to handle initializations</description>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.company.csd.dao.transaction.CompanyHibernateTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <description>
            Database configuration settings.
        <!-- config-->
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=CORE</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>core_user</value>
        </property>     
        <property name="password">
            <value>core_user</value>
        </property> 
        <!-- config-->      
    </bean>


    <!-- Configure DAOFactory -->
    <bean class="com.passmarksecurity.dao.api.DAOFactory" id="daoFactory" init-method="configPostProcess">
        <property name="DAOConfig">
            <ref bean="daoConfig"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- IMPORTANT: Configure this setting first -->

    <!-- This is for Oracle configuration with database images -->
    <bean class="com.passmarksecurity.dao.config.DAOConfigMSSQL" id="daoConfig"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean> 
</beans>
```

When the application runs I get the below exception:

```
    - <Tool failed: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [pmBootstrapConfigs.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [pmBootstrapConfigs.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [pmBootstrapConfigs.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [pmBootstrapConfigs.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [pmBootstrapConfigs.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 24 more
```

if I add `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>`explicitly to the hibernate properties it starts working.

The most common answer available online is that there is some issue in connecting to the DB. So I tried writing a separate piece of code to just access the DB with the same details, and it worked. 
Dont know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML Spring configuration, you must update :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop> 
                <!-- HERE THE DIALECT CONFIGURATION -->
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

From [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html), you must provide the dialect as following :

- A dialect for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 with JDBC Driver 3.0 and above

`<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</prop>`

- A dialect for Microsoft SQL Server 2000 and 2005

`<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>`

Comment: We have multiple DB's depending on the customer, there can be an Oracle Db, SQL Db or db2. As far as I had read hibernate automatically interprets the correct dialect from the driver. Therefore we cannot hardcode the dialect as it will be different for different environments.

Comment: One of the links I went through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null

Answer (score 1):

if you specify your database name you won't need to set the dialect. To do so you can use JpaVendorAdaptor as a property for org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
or HibernatePersistenceProvider (for hibernate versions lower than 5)
In this case if it is microsoft sql server

```
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while testing Mysql-8 with Hibernate-5 & Spring-5. Initially, I had `<prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>` in `hibernateProperties` tag. After 10 mins of testing I was able to add a fix by replacing `<prop key="dialect">` with `<prop key="dialect">`.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: replacing <prop key="dialect"> by <prop key="dialect">, didnt get you?