# @Qualifier is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-4

I have 3 data sources that I set up as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean("foo")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.foo")
    public DataSource foo() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean("bar")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.bar")
    public DataSource bar() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean("baz")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.baz")
    public DataSource baz() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

I am trying to autowire them in to my consumer class as follows:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(
            @Autowired @Qualifier("foo") DataSource foo,
            @Autowired @Qualifier("bar") DataSource bar,
            @Autowired @Qualifier("baz") DataSource baz
            ) {
        ;
    }

}
```

When the app tries to start, I get the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.mypackage.MyClass required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - foo: defined by method 'foo' in class path resource [com/example/DataSourceConfig.class]
    - bar: defined by method 'bar' in class path resource [com/example/DataSourceConfig.class]
    - baz: defined by method 'baz' in class path resource [com/example/DataSourceConfig.class]
```

Why is `@Qualifier` not working?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: Try to remove `@Autowired` from the constructor arguments. (Leave only one above `Myclass` constructor). And in case it's not clear do keep the `@Qualifier`

Comment: @Oleg No luck :(

Comment: Weird, works for me even without naming the beans and `@Qualifier`. Just based on method and parameters names. I am using Spring 4 though not 5.

Comment: Works for me. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/45578689).

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: @Brian I couldn't get it to work and ended up using an entirely different approach. So, I can't test anymore and see if StanislavL's approach would work.

Comment: Alternate idea (food for thought, you may have a specific situation).  ::: Instead of hard coding 3 of them (or however many), consider injecting a collection of them.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338322/spring-di-beans-with-multiple-concretes-picking-one-of-them/52341778#52341778

Answer (score 4):

Make one of the beans primary by adding `@Primary` annotation. Then qualifier should be recognized.

Comment: This woked for me but it is risky to make one bean as primary. I won't consider this as recommended solution

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class MyClass {

    private DataSource foo;
    private DataSource bar; 
    private DataSource baz;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(
            @Qualifier("foo") final DataSource foo,
            @Qualifier("bar") final DataSource bar,
            @Qualifier("baz") final DataSource baz
            ) {
        ;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried that last night as a test for this, no luck. Same error he is getting.

Answer (score 0):

This solution resolves the issue in question, however it does not render a fully working configuration.

1. Set a primary database.
2. Change constructor format.

#### MyClass.java

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    private final DataSource foo;
    private final DataSource bar;
    private final DataSource baz;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Qualifier("foo") DataSource foo,
                   @Qualifier("bar") DataSource bar,
                   @Qualifier("baz") DataSource baz) {

        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;

    }

}
```

#### DataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean("foo")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.foo")
    public DataSource foo() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean("bar")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.bar")
    public DataSource bar() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean("baz")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.baz")
    public DataSource baz() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

This leaves the error `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`. For that, I would recommend following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null) as it focuses on the topic of the question, and this question is focused around `@Bean` names and referencing them with `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Making bean primary is risky and not advisable.