# Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have search all over the internet to solve this problem but found no solution. Please hope someone can be of help.
In my spring boot application. I am using hikari for the first time to access two different datasource but getting the above error.

## My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.deanace.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-oauth2</name>
    <description>This have combined technology</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
</project>
```

## application.properties

```
server.port=8080
# ===============================
# DATASOURCE
# ===============================
# DataSource (Postgresql offline).
spring.datasource.one.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.one.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/flexpay_africa
spring.datasource.one.username=postgres
spring.datasource.one.password=password
# DataSource (Postgresql offline).
spring.datasource.two.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.two.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/flexpay_db
spring.datasource.two.username=postgres
spring.datasource.two.password=password

# JPA
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

## Datasource1

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.deanace.oauth2.repository.datasourceOne",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryBeanOne",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerOne"
)
public class DataSourceOne {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.one.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource DataSourceOne(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerOne(){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBeanOne().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanOne() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.deanace.oauth2.entities");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

## Datasource2

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.deanace.oauth2.repository.datasourceTwo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerTwo"
)
public class DataSourceTwo {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.two.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.two.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.two.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.two.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource DataSourceTwo(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerTwo(){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.deanace.oauth2.entities");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

## Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBeanOne' defined in class path resource [com/deanace/oauth2/persistence/DataSourceOne.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.deanace.oauth2.SpringSecurityOauth2Application.main(SpringSecurityOauth2Application.java:59) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your database running and able to connect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out.
My Datasource1 and Datasource2 classes were missing config.setJdbcUrl(url)

```
@Bean
    public DataSource DataSourceTwo(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

and in my LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I also failed to include entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceTwo());

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBeanTwo() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceTwo());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.deanace.oauth2.entities");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```