# How to resolve Hibernate's error when running the project?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernateexception

When I run my web applicaton, the error below is shown.

**can you help me to fix it please?**

I'm using hibernate framework, the project was running successfully, but after adding a restful web services and remove it, the project throw this error.

I will show you more information if you want.

```
Deploying on WildFly Application Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Undeploying ...
Initial deploying px-fs-web-stage to C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Stage 2018\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\deployments\px-fs-web-stage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
Completed initial distribution of px-fs-web-stage
Deploying C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Stage 2018\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\deployments\px-fs-web-stage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Les services ont Ã©chouÃ©\" => {\"jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"px-fs-web-stage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#ma.px.fs.stage_px-fs-web-stage_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU\\\"\" => \"org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set\"}}"
cd C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Stage 2018\sypex-stage\px-fs-web-stage; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_161" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 package\""
Scanning for projects...
```

my hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName" default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <beans profile="default" default-lazy-init="true">

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:/SypexXADS" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>ma.px.management.repository.service.bo</value>
                </list>
            </property>

            <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory" /> 
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="1" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <jpa:repositories base-package="ma.px.management.repository.service.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

        <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    </beans>

</beans>
```

**I did not change anythings in my hibernate configuration. I just remove a web service servlet from my web.xml, Note that it is a maven project**

Thank you.

Comment: `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect'`.  I would start there.  Given the lack of [mcve] on this question that's as good as we can do to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `hibernate.dialect`
add it to your jpaPropertyMap with database dialect class as value

below example for MySQL

```
<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
     <map>
         <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
          ...other items
     </map>
</property>
```