# How to fix this error org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to using hibernate with mysql connection
This error occur
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be       null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

> **Mainclass**

```
package com.gontuseries.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student_Info student=new Student_Info();
//      .buildSessionFactory()
        student.setName("aaa");
        student.setRollNo(1);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

//      SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        cfg.addClass(Student_Info.class);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(student);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateTutorial</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1370</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

<mapping class="com.gontuseries.hibernate.Student_Info"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

> **Entity Class**

```
package com.gontuseries.hibernate;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT_INFORMATION")
public class Student_Info {
    @Id
    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private int rollNo;
    private String name;
}
```

> **Error**

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.gontuseries.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

Comment: See the log if your configuration file loaded or not

Comment: You use Spring Boot?