# Migrating from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2, error on multiple data sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am migrating my application from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2 (and hopefully from Tomcat to Hikari in the process). I've solved all the compilation errors, but now I'm getting this error (I've removed most of the stacktrace as I see no important info on it):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pexEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xisumavoid/gateway/db/PexDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I have 2 classes that act as database configuration, as my application has to access 2 databases (Named 'primary' and 'pex'). The `PexDbConfig` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "pexEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "pexTransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "com.xisumavoid.gateway.db.pex.repositories" }
)
public class PexDbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "pexDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pex.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "pexEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pexEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("pexDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.xisumavoid.gateway.db.pex.models")
                .persistenceUnit("pex")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "pexTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager pexTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("pexEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    pexEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(pexEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the messy code, long class names are hard to deal with.
Also, in case it's needed, here's the relevant config section:

```
## DB - PRIMARY
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/primary
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

## DB - PEX
pex.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
pex.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pex
pex.datasource.username=user
pex.datasource.password=password
```

How do I fix this, or even better yet, is there a way to do this in a simpler way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hibernate 5.2.17

Answer (score 0):

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null) , adding

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

to my `application.properties` did the trick.