# Error : when i need generate entities by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

i canot create hibernate.cfg.xml and i can`t understand this error 
because i set dialect data base  oracle 10g 
but i use oracle database 11 xe

> Error :   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
>
> > org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:184)
> >       at
> >     org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_3.internal.util.MetadataHelper.buildFromMetadataSources(MetadataHelper.java:49)
> >       at
> >     org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_3.internal.util.MetadataHelper.getMetadata(MetadataHelper.java:21)
> >       at
> >     org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_3.internal.ConfigurationFacadeImpl.getMetadata(ConfigurationFacadeImpl.java:174)
> >       at
> >     org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_3.internal.util.ConfigurationMetadataDescriptor.createMetadata(ConfigurationMetadataDescriptor.java:20)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.buildMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:207)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.getMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:57)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.setupContext(AbstractExporter.java:178)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:105)
> >       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor581.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> >     org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
> >       at
> >     org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractExporterFacade.start(AbstractExporterFacade.java:72)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.openContentStream(NewConfigurationWizard.java:301)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.access$2(NewConfigurationWizard.java:295)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard$1.getInitialContents(NewConfigurationWizard.java:163)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.createNewFile(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:380)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.performFinish(NewConfigurationWizard.java:198)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:772)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:411)
> >       at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)   at
> >     org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
> >       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
> >       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5686)     at
> >     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1370)    at
> >     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4940)
> >       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4518)
> >       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)    at
> >     org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)     at
> >     org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:133)
> >       at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)    at
> >     org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
> >       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
> >       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5686)     at
> >     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1370)    at
> >     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4940)
> >       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4518)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1170)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
> >       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:667)   at
> >     org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:597)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
> >       at
> >     org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
> >       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >       at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> >     org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)  at
> >     org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)     at
> >     org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)     at
> >     org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1471) Caused by:
> >     org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo
> >     cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set   at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
> >       ... 73 more

```
public class HibernateUtils {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
           try {
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = 
               new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metaData = 
                new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
           } catch (Throwable th) {
            System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
          }
        }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

Comment: Please share hibernate.cfg.xml