# Spring Data JPA: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get access to SQLite by using "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa".

And the "application.properties" is used.
The dialect is set at the "spring.jpa.database-platform".
But the error of "DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null" happens.
What should I do?

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.luminous.spring.dialect.SQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:D:\\employee.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect` in application.properties file.

Also refer [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26548505/6572971) for more possible solutions.

Comment: This will not work if you have to connect to 2 different database vendors such as DB2 and Oracle for example.  How would you set hibernate dialect in that case?

Comment: In that case you might be configuring multiple data sources and can add dialect as part of configurations.

Comment: thanks.  I did that, posted SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296481/spring-boot-hibernate-error-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null-when