# Why doesn't spring boot application launch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

My initial program was intended to insert data into my database. I have 4 tables, where data is inserted, and for optimization's sake, I'm doing that in a seperate thread, because entities are created asynchronous. I'm adding entities to a queue with consume method.

```
package main.database;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import main.utilities.LogUtil;

import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class EntityManager {
    static final int BUFFER = 10000;
    static Queue<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    static ExecutorService executor;

    public static void open() {
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::open started.");
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(EntityManager::save);
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::open ended.");
    }

    public static void consume(Object entity) {
        LogUtil.logger.trace("EntityManager::consume added entity [%s] to queue.".formatted(entity.getClass()));
        queue.add(entity);
    }

    private static void save() {
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::save opening session.");
        Session session = Hibernate.createSession();
        while (!executor.isShutdown()) {
            int count = queue.size();
            if (count < BUFFER) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LogUtil.logger.fatal(e);
                }
            } else {
                LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::save begin transaction");
                session.beginTransaction();
                for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER; i++) {
                    Object entity = queue.poll();
                    LogUtil.logger.trace("EntityManager::save: saving [%s]".formatted(entity.getClass().getSimpleName()));
                    session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
                }
                LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::save commit transaction");
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::save closing session.");
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::save begin last transaction");
        int remainingCount = queue.size();
        session.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < remainingCount; i++) {
            Object entity = queue.poll();
            LogUtil.logger.trace("EntityManager::save: saving [%s]".formatted(entity.getClass().getSimpleName()));
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::save commit last transaction");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public static void close() {
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::close started.");
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::close executor.shutdown()");
        executor.shutdown();
        while (queue.size() > 0) {
            Thread.onSpinWait();
        }
        try {
            boolean isTerminated = executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if (!isTerminated) {
                LogUtil.logger.error("ThreadPoolExecutor termination timeout. Fix your bug.");
                System.exit(3);
            }
            LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::close executor is terminated.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LogUtil.logger.fatal("", e);
        }
        LogUtil.logger.info("EntityManager::close ended.");
    }

}
```

After a while, I decided to add web api to my application using Spring Boot. Spring Data JPA is needed, because some POST requests insert data into my database. But Spring Data JPA is conflicting with my Hibernate dependency already in use.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>landsreyk</groupId>
    <artifactId>search-engine</artifactId>
    <version>4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


</project>
```

And my hibernate configuration file 'hibernate.cfg.xml'

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search_engine?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">landsreyk</property>
        <property name="connection.password">12345678</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="model.Page"/>
        <mapping class="model.Field"/>
        <mapping class="model.Word"/>
        <mapping class="model.Index"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I also have spring configuration file application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search-engine
    username: landsreyk
    password: 12345678
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
sites:
  - url: http://www.playback.ru
    name: PlayBack.ru
  - url: https://www.lenta.ru
    name: Лента.ру
  - url: https://www.skillbox.ru
    name: Skillbox
user-agent: LandsreykSearchBot/1.0 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)
referrer: http://www.google.com
web-interface: /admin
```

So, I added a simple controller DefaultContoller.java

```
package main.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@RestController
public class DefaultController
{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public String index()
  {
    return LocalDateTime.now().toString();
  }
}
```

And my Main class is:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

But tomcat won't launch because of some cumbersome problem with hibernate, which I don't quite understand.

```
C:\Users\HP\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=61862:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath E:\java\skillbox\java_basics\FinalProject\search-engine\target\classes;E:\java\skillbox\java_basics\FinalProject\search-engine\lib\word-processor.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.0\spring-boot-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.13\spring-core-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.13\spring-jcl-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.0\jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.0\jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.0\jackson-core-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.13\spring-web-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.13\spring-beans-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.13\spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.13\spring-aop-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.13\spring-context-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.13\spring-expression-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.13\spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.6.0\spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.6.0\spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.13\spring-orm-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.13\spring-tx-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.13\spring-aspects-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.14.3\jsoup-1.14.3.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.22\lombok-1.18.22.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.25\mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.1.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.11.20\byte-buddy-1.11.20.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\txw2-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.14.1\log4j-core-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.7\commons-validator-1.7.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.4\commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\2.1\commons-digester-2.1.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar main.Main

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
нояб. 27, 2021 9:49:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
нояб. 27, 2021 9:49:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
нояб. 27, 2021 9:49:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
нояб. 27, 2021 9:49:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
09:49:06.549 [main] ERROR - Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
нояб. 27, 2021 9:49:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
09:49:06.597 [main] ERROR - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 33 more


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My project structure looks like:

[image: packages and structure of my project]

Why did that error occur? Is it because I'm using Hibernate.Session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was adviced by [Geno Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9035237/geno-chen).
I followed the link [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null)

It turns out that, hibernate configuration, i.e. hibernate.cfg.xml is not needed, when using spring boot configuration file.
And I also edited my application.yml spring configuration file. This is what I added

```
database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
show-sql: false
```

So now it looks like:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search-engine
    username: landsreyk
    password: 12345678
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
sites:
  - url: http://www.playback.ru
    name: PlayBack.ru
  - url: https://www.lenta.ru
    name: Лента.ру
  - url: https://www.skillbox.ru
    name: Skillbox
user-agent: LandsreykSearchBot/1.0 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)
referrer: http://www.google.com
web-interface: /admin
```

Now my web app launches without errors and initial page is shown at localhost:8080
where Apache Tomcat placed it.