# Is there a way to create a database with the entity first aproach in spring boot?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to create the tables of a Microsoft SQL DB from objects, in Spring Boot. Is there a way to do that? If it is, can someone tell me at least the steps on how i should do that?

Comment: see documentation [howto.data-initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

First, you need to create a class from your object and pass it the `@Entity` annotation like so:

```java
@Entity
public class DemoEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String demoStringProperty;
    private Double demoDoubleProperty;
}
```

Then let hibernate know that it should create the entity from the class by adding this to the `application.properties` file:

```
... database url, username, pass ...
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

`create-drop` insead of `update` would accomplish the same thing in your case but there is a difference which you can read more in the [community documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl).

Comment: Yup, i tried this already, but i have the following problem. I have my class created.
And in application.properties i have those lines:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database:BikeShopDB;integratedSecurity=true;
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update. The problem is that i get an error saying that entityManagerFactory can t be created.

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes i do have it

Comment: I've added those in in the `application.properties`:
`spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2016Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop` and now i got this `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

Comment: Check if [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null) can help you. The following error can occur when the database server is down, you use the wrong credentials, you connect to the wrong database server, etc..

Comment: I checked the server port to be on :1433, and its hosted by me, so it must be on localhost. it does not have credentials as i use the `integratedSecurity:true` option.