# Why can't Spring Boot deduce Hibernate dialect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I can't start up my Spring Boot application

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: 
Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due 
to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata 
(please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a 
custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
```

Here are my application properties (all of them):

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    username: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:postgres}
    url: ${POSTGRES_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${POSTGRES_USERNAME}}
```

Here's my pom. I tried to trim to include only relevant parts (while ensuring it's still a valid pom you can copy and paste). Basically, to reproduce it, you only need to create a Boot project with a Data starter (maybe the driver too) so that Boot's autoconfiguration (the one with a `DataSource`) kicks in

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>token-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>token-service</name>
    <description>token-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I explicitly set the `spring.jpa.database-platform` property, it starts up fine. However, I never did it before when I used MySQL

```yaml
spring:
# ...
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Why can't Boot deduce the dialect?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548505/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null) might be helpful.

Comment: @BillHorvath please see the edit. I don't understand why I didn't have to set the `database-platform` property when I used MySQL

Comment: The `url: ${POSTGRES_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${POSTGRES_USERNAME}}` looks unusual to me, but I haven't done Spring Boot in a while. What did it look like when you used MySQL?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you're jdbc url is wrong.  Hibernate often says it can't determine the dialect when it can't connect.

Check with a literal configuration, and prove that first.

Comment: @BillHorvath pretty much the same, save for a few extra parameters and no dynamic placeholders, `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true`

Comment: I think you probably meant to use something like this: `url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_URL}/${POSTGRES_USERNAME}`

Comment: @BillHorvath can't say I did

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring Boot with Postgres without setting the Dialect manually, but you have to keep this in mind.

**Only Hibernate 6 or higher can do the automatic Dialect resolution based on your database library en connection. Otherwise, you have to provide it manually.**

So, make sure you are using Hibernate v6 or higher. If not update it (be carefu, maybe you will have to update some other things in your code), or just set the dialect just like you did; it doesn't impact so much in most cases.

You can see how Hibernate v6 deduces the Dialect and why this only happens after that version [HERE](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-dialect/)