Spring Boot can't connect to PostgreSQL
I have a Spring Boot project that works fine on Windows, but on Fedora with PostgreSQL running in a Podman container, I get Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided).  I have added that configuration, but continue to get the same message. My code can be found here. What am I missing?
This question is different from this one because I already attempted the solution provided by the exception message.

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78044805/22096771

I do have Hibernate 6.
