I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot WAR file to a server, but the application is not starting correctly, and I am encountering errors
I am trying to host my java spring boot api project on a cloud server with below configurations-
Spring Boot Version: 3.2.1
Tomcat Version: 10.1.7
Java Version: 21.0.4
But after deploying my war file I get below error logs in catalina.out
Error deploying web application archive [/home/d3790/jvm/apache-tomcat-10.1.7/domains/dknotihrms.in.net/ROOT.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[dknotihrms.in.net].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:276)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:143)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:348)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        ... 70 more

I have already checked by deploying the war file on the external tomcat server with version 10.1.7 on my local system and it works but as soon as I try to deploy it at cloud server I face above problem.
I am new when it comes to hosting application on live server. Any help would be appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036592/why-cant-spring-boot-deduce-hibernate-dialect

The error indicates:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect'

You have to add the dialect in your hibernate.cfg.xml or the properties file.
This is the list of dialects, as reference.

It didn't work...Also if that was the case why would my war file work perfectly at my local system when deploying it at external tomcat server.

Are you including the properties or the xml in the war? The exception is clear.
